# Is there a way to make setTooltip() case sensitive

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

When using Button.setToolTip("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") with Sentence case. The button text displays as Start case "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog". Is there a way to change the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want is to unset the text-transform style `text-transform: capitalize;` of the tooltip. Add the below CSS style to your site CSS file after Forge Viewer's.

```css
.adsk-viewing-viewer.dark-theme .adsk-control-tooltip {
    text-transform: unset;
}
```

Comment: I may not have explained it correctly. I don't want to convert the letter case before it goes into setToolTip(). I want SetToolTip() to display the same letter case on the UI.

This is what I put into setToolTip("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") 

This is what the button on the UI displays "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog"

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I updated my answer.